# How to call onClick function a component into another component's render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component called Spot.jsx which looks like this:

```
const Spot = ({title, toolber, onClick}) => {

//a lot of code written here

}

Spot.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string,
    toolber: PropTypes.shape(),
    onClick: PropTypes.func,
}
```

I am using this component inside another one like this:

```
...
<Spot 
  title={account.AccountName}
  onClick={() => "mySite/accountoverview?id=" + account.AccountId}
    ...
>
...
</Spot>
```

The problem is with the link, when I hover over it is getting coloured as it should be but it doesn't do anything when I click on it.

Also, console is empty, no errors

Do you have any advice to solve this?

Comment: The issue seems very apparent. `onClick` is an event listener and needs to be a function, but you are passing a string in.

Comment: @Chris I made it do be a function, tried it like that before but didn't work neither

Comment: What you have done is a function, but that function doesn't actually do anything at all. You are just creating a string but you don't do anything with it.

Comment: You also have a typo, it's "toolbar" with an "a" :)

Answer (score 0):

The `onClick` prop of the `Spot` component needs to be a function. If you mean to open that string as a URL I'll suggest to pass the `AccountId` as a prop and kill the `onClick`. Then inside your `Spot` you may do:

`` const Spot = ({title, toolber, AccountId}) => {
  return <a href={ `mySite/accountoverview?id=${AccountId}` }>{ title }</a>;
} ``

And use it like so:

`<Spot title={account.AccountName} AccountId={account.AccountId} />`

Comment: isn't it possible to do it like a function? I updated my question by using `onClick` as a function but it still doesn't works. now I don't get any errors, I click on it and nothing happens

Comment: Well with `onClick` you are saying "Tell me when that link is clicked". What happens after that is your responsibility. If you want to do it as a function you have to manually change the browser's URL either by using history API or with `window.location.href=...`. For example: `() => 
 window.location.href = "mySite/accountoverview?id=" + account.AccountId`. In your example you are just returning a string of that click handler which is doing nothing.

Comment: I don't know the context but if you want to forward the user to another page you better use a link `<a>`.